# Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python

как решать данную задачу;
Напишите программу, которая рассчитает сколько бензина израсходовал транспорт в среднем на 100 км. формула: Расход = литры израсходованные на дорогу / пройденный путь * 100 Возвратите расход. на пйтоне

```py
def get_fuel_consumption(length_km, litres, gen):
    pass
```

Comment: задача в одну строчку, даже циклов и условий нет. Если вам даже такое не под силу, то или возьмите учебник, или бросайте это дело

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_fuel_consumption(length_km, litres):
    gen = litres / lenght_km * 100
    return gen
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]